# Trouble loading data from JSON file into HTML table with js function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

The title says it all, I'm struggling to get data from a json file to an HTML table using a js function with jquery, but the data from the json file isn't loading onto the table. I'm also using bootstrap.
I got the error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Nuno/Desktop/my%20shit/Faculdade/ITW/trabalho%20lab/info.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

JSON:

```
[
    {"Age": "18", "Email": "qweqwe@ua.pt", "Phone": "123456789", "Adress": "Lisbon", "Languages": "English, Portuguese, (Limited) Spanish"}
]
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("info.json", function(data){
    var mydata = '';
    $.each(data, function(key,value){
      mydata += '<tr>';
      mydata+= '<td>'+value.age+'</td>';
      mydata+= '<td>'+value.email+'</td>';
      mydata+= '<td>'+value.phone+'</td>';
      mydata+= '<td>'+value.adress+'</td>';
      mydata+= '<td>'+value.languages+'</td>';
      mydata += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#personalInfo').append(mydata);
  });
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="personalInfo"> 
              <tr> 
                <th> 
                  Age
                </th> 
                <th> 
                  Email 
                </th> 
                <th> 
                  Phone 
                </th> 
                <th> 
                  Adress
                </th> 
                <th> 
                  Languages
                </th> 
              </tr> 
          </table> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Is there any error you can share with us?

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: Looks like you're lower-casing your keys but the keys in the json are sentence-case

Comment: info.json:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED is the error I get in the console

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Nuno/Desktop/my%20shit/Faculdade/ITW/trabalho%20lab/info.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
I also got this error

Comment: Your issue is CORS. Make sure you edit your question and include this error.

Comment: You need to run this on a localhost server not in `file://` protocol. Ajax is blocked in `file://` for security reasons. There are numerous ways to quickly set up a localhost server on your machine

Comment: is there any way for me to be able to run this in `file://` protocol?

Comment: Well you can override chrome security settings. You can also install a CORS extension. In general localhost is safest long term. A web search for all alternatives should quickly get results

Comment: you have saved me thank youuuuuu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using Chrome. There's a restriction in Chrome on accessing any files via xhr requests starting with file: //.

There's more info here http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=171316324d16747b&hl=en

Suggestion:

If you are using Google Chrome, it is intentional that AJAX on file:/// paths never works.

[crbug/40787](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the help, if you ever have this issue check your console. If you get the error "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Nuno/Desktop/my%20shit/Faculdade/ITW/trabalho%20lab/info.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https." The problem isn't the code.
I managed to get it working using the Live Server extension in VS Code.